# Django field not taking the given input

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a login code in which the create two model where the data is being stored the first one is the default admin User model and the second one that is custom field

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class AppUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)  # You should use a secure password storage method.
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
            ('O', 'Other'),
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,default='M')
    area = models.TextField(max_length=100,unique=False,default='Select City')
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default='1')
    


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from .models import AppUser

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    ]
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            required=True,
            label='Gender',
        )
    class Meta:
        model = AppUser
        fields = ['username','email','password','first_name','last_name','area','phone_number']
```

Now the fields till gender is working just fine but after it the area and the phone number is not taking the user input the default shows up in the table;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly it's not a good practice to set default values that do not have specific reason like `Select City` at `area` or default number `1`. They should be null.

Secondly if you send a request that does not have `gender`, `area` or `phone_number`, they will get the default values you set, else it will set the values user gave.

That's why it does not require the user to set them. you should do this instead if you want to make them requiring for user to set them:

```py
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
area = models.TextField(max_length=100,unique=False)
phone_number = models.IntegerField()
```

or you can make them optional:

```py
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,null=True, blank=True)
area = models.TextField(max_length=100,unique=False,null=True, blank=True)
phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```